# json response in jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

i'm trying to put a json response in a jquery data table , but in data table it's not showing any response.

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
 <table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr><th class="site_name">Name</th><th>Url </th><th>Type</th><th>Last modified</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
$("#example").dataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "sAjaxSource": "http://url",
  "aoColumns": [{
    "mData":"name",
    "sTitle": "site name"
  },{
    "mData": "createdBy"

  },{
    "mData": "createdBySafeId"
  },{
    "mData": "lastUpdated"
  },{
    "mData":"tag"
  }]
});
  </script>

<!--   <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
example 
</textarea> -->
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the response

```
 [
  {
    "id": 22,
    "name": "FPS-T25831236-1450251690209",
    "lastUpdated": 1450251690213,
    "createdBy": "Janaki",
    "onBoarded": 1450251668000,
    "activeFlag": true,
    "createdBySafeId": "UC192791",
    "sourceApplication": "FPS",
    "subSource": "T25831236",
    "type": "orderid",
    "tag": [
      "Arunesh",
      "mamatha"
    ],
    "comment": null,
    "privateNote": true,
    "reference": [
      "T25831111"
    ],
    "expiryDate": 1606630852
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "name": "FPS-T25831236-1450251728342",
    "lastUpdated": 1450251728347,
    "createdBy": "Janaki",
    "onBoarded": 1450251668000,
    "activeFlag": true,
    "createdBySafeId": "UC192791",
    "sourceApplication": "FPS",
    "subSource": "T25831236",
    "type": "orderid",
    "tag": [
      "Arunesh",
      "mamatha"
    ],
    "comment": null,
    "privateNote": true,
    "reference": [
      "T25831111"
    ],
    "expiryDate": 1606630852
  }
]
```

when i'm trying to show the response in the data table..it's showing the blank rows . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have enabled server-side processing mode with `"serverSide": true` but your response doesn't have the appropriate structure for that mode. You also need to use `"sAjaxDataProp": ""` because your response is a plain array.

Use the following code instead:

```
$("#example").dataTable({
  "sAjaxSource": "http://url",
  "sAjaxDataProp": "",
  "aoColumns": [{
    "mData":"name",
    "sTitle": "site name"
  },{
    "mData": "createdBy"

  },{
    "mData": "createdBySafeId"
  },{
    "mData": "lastUpdated"
  },{
    "mData":"tag"
  }]
});
```

Comment: yeah ..i tried with "sAjaxDataProp": "", but no luck .. i removed {
    "mData":"name",
    "sTitle": "site name"
  } .as this was not required much . , now i'm getting this error   dataTable.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://url. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.  in chrome

Comment: @avi, that's completely different problem. `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` means that you're trying to perform cross-origin request (source domain differs from target domain) and the target (`fpappol01.emea1.cis.trcloud:9033`) doesn't allow it.

Comment: @avi, You either need to allow [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the target host, or use JSONP format if target host supports it.

Comment: The cross-origin problem is gone now..i've added this extension in chrome >> (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US) . ,  but still it can't load the data into the data table.

Answer (score 0):

Please use a more current version of DataTables! Other than that you'll need to give us some more ideas about how you want tags to display. In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/dox6b1tb/) I'm joining them with commas but the world's your lobster.

Basically a render function is what you want on the `tags` field:

```
{
  "data": "tag",
  "render": function(d) {
    return d.join(", ")
  }
}
```

Comment: actually the json i expect is coming from the server